# Cross origin access while calling third party API with authorization headers in AJAX jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-browser, cross-domain

I am calling sandbox API with post method also using authorization headers but it's showing following error. I have tried cross domain extension in Chrome that time it's working fine, but after disable its showing error.

**Here is ajax the code.**

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://'+BASE_URL+'/v3/company/'+companyid+'/account?minorversion='+minorversion,
        type: 'POST',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType:'json',
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2IiwiYWxnIjoiZGlyIn0..ok78Pkecig1pIq_NoLipeA.2JHoUufZlQIJxlTE58Vqd0FP-PHl4XTfVCa_O9G66wylq6ATGc3jXp5gH9ecAbul_NbjFUQvBGp4Mu_6Zusovr7Uo70iaFr3zcwcv2bTRg7cdNV0e4ah-CFcYizPT2P4oGG4EUbO-om.30-lSg1HjG21HrckVEFBSg','Accept':'application/json','Content-Type':'application/json'},
        data: json,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
```

The following is the error showing in console area

> Failed to load https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/*************/account?minorversion=4: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://intuitdev.qwesys.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Please check this by change the browser like firefox or any other. Have you try this?

Comment: Yes but getting same error.

Comment: Does the documentation say the allow CORS requests?

Comment: Yes api perfectly working in postman but in ajax its showing error